# How to put the sheet name in a new column in google sheets whilst combining sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am combining multiple sheets and would like to put the sheet name in a new column. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
=query({'L&D1'!A2:E;{"","","","",mySheetName()};'L&D2'!A2:E},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")
```

The mySheetName() function

```
function mySheetName() {
  var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  return key;
}
```

Comment: Can you visually clarify the expected outcome? Might be useful to provide a copy of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

change A1 to fit your scenario:

```
=QUERY({'L&D1'!A2:E; 
 {"","","","",INDIRECT(mySheetName()&"!A1")}; 'L&D2'!A2:E},
 "where Col1 is not null")
```